# Problem with a PVC Gate

Tags: repair

I have an outside 6 foot high and 4 feet wide PVC gate. the problem is it swings open way too far especially when windy.I have a wall there that the gate constantly hits.

Comment: Fit a post with a catch to hold the gate open at the max point you want...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A diagram would really help us help you; please edit it into your question.